# Random sampling in python3

Tags: python

Suppose I have two lists A = [1,2,3,4] and B=[a,b,c,d]. I have to do random sampling such that my new list could look like this C= [1 or a , 2 or b , 3 or c , 4 or d], there is also a constrain that that the list C should have 50 % data from both  A and B.
Input:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = ['a','b','c','d']
```

Comment: So, you use `random.choose` to pick two from A, and two from B, and shuffle the result.

Comment: You'd make a list that's half True, half False, and the same length as the input. Shuffle it and use it to pick from A or B.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could randomly [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) the indices to ensure having half and half:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = ['a','b','c','d']

import random 
idx = set(random.sample(range(len(A)), len(A)//2))

C = [a if i in idx else b for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(A, B))]
```

Example output: `['a', 2, 3, 'd']`

Comment: @Mark because this won't enforce equal origin size, this could yield `['a', 'b', 'c', 4]`

Comment: Ah, yes, I misread.